# App Store release using wrong Core Data Version

Tags: ios, core-data, release, versioning

My released version appears to be using a old model version of Core Data, xxxDB 101j instead of xxxDB as defined in the VersionInfo.plist (package contents of xxx.xcarchive submitted to the app store). This has not been an issue on development devices or releases to TestFlight.

It is using the last listed version in VersionInfo.plist, not the version defined in the NSManagedObjectModel_CurrentVersionName property. Interestingly all the versions have a .mom file including xxxDB but xxxDB also has an .omo file as well.

Has anyone bumped into this issue and found a work around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workaround is to add a new version model, make that the current version, clean, archive and submit.  At this point in time, the NSManagedObjectModel_CurrentVersionName property is not used when your app is submitted to the app store.  It uses the last listed model in the VersionInfo.plist.

The behavior in the testing/adhoc environment is different to go live